# What are Weber class field's weak points?

Tags: mathematics-social-history, hilbert

These days, I'm interested in class field theory.

I know that Weber first made his own 'class field' and then Hilbert made his own field, 'Hilbert class field'.

By the way, were there so many weak points in Weber's class field that Hilbert had to create a Hilbert class field? If so, what are the weak points?

Comment: Re " I know that Weber first made his own 'class field' ": Can you point to the relevant publication? I have not been able to find anything relevant so far. Just to confirm, the "Weber" in question is Heinrich Martin Weber (1842-1913), correct?

Comment: Yes, you're right! I wrote about Heinrich Martin Weber. And I saw 'History of class field theory' by Keith Conrad and wikipedia

Comment: I *think* the relevant publication may be: H. Weber, "Die allgemeinen Grundlagen der Galois'schen Gleichungstheorie." *Mathematische Annalen*, Vol. 43, No. 4, 1893, pp. 521-549; in particular the section "Körper" on [pp. 526-528](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN235181684_0043?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B540%5D%2C%22view%22%3A%22info%22%7D)

Comment: Thanks, I will find it!

Comment: Note that I already provided a clickable link to a scan of Weber's 1893 publication. The publication is in German. Basically it says that a group becomes a field if it supports two compositions, addition and multiplication, both of which must be commutative.

Comment: FWIW, I don't see where Weber used the term class field (German: "Klassenkörper"). That seems to be a concept / term introduced later, e.g. I see a 1903 publication by Felix Bernstein, "Über die Klassenkörper eines algebraischen Zahlkörpers" (On the class fields of an algebraic number field).